# Why is my computer displaying the wrong graphics card model?

Tags: graphics-card, computer-building

I built a PC that runs Windows 7 64-bit. Everything seemed fine initially, but Device Management lists my graphics card as a Radeon HD 4800 series. I have an HD 5870. What's wrong/how can I make my computer recognize the card?

Comment: Operating system?

Comment: Are you 100% sure? I know that sounds harsh, but mislabelling has been known to happen.

Comment: windows 7 64 bit. it is definitly a 5870 because it the only part thats not new, been using the card for years

Comment: years? the card has only been out for a year and 6 months, sept 09...

Comment: It might be a 4870, the 5870 has only been out as @Kyle pointed out, for a year and 6 months.

Answer (score 1):

Go to AMD [Support & Drivers](http://support.amd.com/us/Pages/AMDSupportHub.aspx) and enter the required values in the section "Download Drivers" and click the button "View results". Or, as you have now entered your OS version, go straight [here](http://sites.amd.com/us/game/downloads/Pages/radeon_win7-64.aspx).

Once you have downloaded the right driver, install it and then reboot.